# Invalid WebHook Signature

Tags: github, webhooks, azure-functions

I created a GitHub Webhook function, copied and pasted the `Function URL` and `GitHub Secret` to the GitHub to the WebHook I created in GitHub and I keep getting the following error.

```
{"Message":"The WebHook signature provided by the 'X-Hub-Signature' header
  field does not match the value expected by the 'GitHubWebHookReceiver'
  receiver. WebHook request is invalid."}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: nothing you're doing there sounds wrong, but that error indicates it has a bad secret. Could you try creating a new key via the keys menu on the develop tab and see if you still get there error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it turns out the `GitHub Secret` from the Develop page matches the `_master` key from the `Admin Keys (All Functions)` keys on the Manage page.

When I used the `default` key from the `Function Keys` it started working. By the names of those sections that sounds like the key I actually want to use and maybe the portal is displaying the wrong one in the GitHub Secret field.

Not sure if this is the answer or a workaround.

Comment: Jeremy, sounds like an issue with the key being displayed by default. Your approach is correct. I've created an issue to track this here: https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/797

Comment: Really glad I found this. The GitHub error message wasn't helpful to me at all :)